# Oracle database 12.2.0 login

Tags: oracle

I cannot login into oracle database.

After installing Database 12.2.0 (named as TX) in command line I am typing:
sqlplus system/manager@tx
And it gives me an invalid user error.
I cannot login as a dba or sys and nothing else.
My service is running, after "tnsping tx" it looks ok.
After lsnrctl status it shows me that my instance TX is READY

Now, again, when I trying to login into tx database using system/manager it says it is wrong username/password. I didn't change anything during installation.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: _" wrong username/password."_.   Please be precise when reporting errors (and commands that produced them).  I presume you mean "ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied"  Oracle is too dumb to lie about that.  It also means you actually got to a database to see if the credentials were correct.  Therefore, we can already know that the instance is running, the database is open, and the listener knows about it, and network correctly routed to listener.  The _only_ issue is that you provided either an incorrect username or an incorrect password for said user.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `SYSTEM` user's password is "manager"?

---

At operating system's command prompt, logged in as user who "owns" Oracle software (usually the user who installed Oracle database), run

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

Slash says that you're a *trusted* user and will let you in. Once you're connected, you can change password for any user in that database as

```
alter user system identified by your_new_password;
```

Comment: User `SYSTEM/manager` was the default in earlier Oracle releases

Comment: I know, @Wernfried. Though, nobody stops you from providing it while installing any Oracle database version, right? So *maybe* the OP did that; or *though* they did it.

Comment: Most probably - I installed an Oracle database only once in my life during a training.